# Game Center Integration in cocos2dx

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am very new to cocos2d-x and wanted to integrate game center in my code.
I have found my solutions, but not finding any accurate solution.
Kindly help me for the same in step by step way.

Answer (score 0):

it’s not well documented but please take a look at:

https://github.com/hovergames/avalon/blob/master/avalon/GameCenter.h
https://github.com/hovergames/avalon/tree/master/avalon/platform/ios/gamecenter

And (currently) you have to add `@public` infront of `RootViewController *viewController` in your `AppController.h`. It’s not pretty but it should work

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
But I am confused with .mm file, as cocos2d-x contains .cpp
And also kindly explain me the content of RootViewController related to game center.

Comment: I am new to cocos2d-x, thus kindly hepl me in step by step process to integrate game center using cocos2d-x.

Comment: Please explain Game center integration for multiplatform in cocos2d-x.